# How to Formate time like time in string to convert into hrs am/pm in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to convert String time like `"00:00:00"` to `12:00 am` and `"13:00:00"` to `"1:00 pm"`.

Thanks for any help :}

Comment: Look at [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for visiting my question but i found a solution and i drop a solution for developers regarding my problem so it's help other Developers :}

**Answer**

```
print(DateFormat.jm().format(DateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse("00:00:00")));
```